# Como edito columnas ya creadas para hacerlas columnas calculadas en sql server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, excel

Hola estoy creando un a base de datos apartir de una macro en excel , esta la importe en sql server pero ciertas columnas no calculan como en el excel me pueden decir como editar esas condiciones intente hacerlo con este codigo pero no fue posible

```
Alter table [dbo].[Project Details]
Alter column [GATE_DATE] as (
Case  when [CURRENT_GATE]='No dates' then ' No dates'
when [CURRENT_GATE]=1 then [G1 Plan_Date]
when [CURRENT_GATE]='Closed' then ' Closed'
when [CURRENT_GATE]= 2 then [G2 Plan_Date]
when [CURRENT_GATE]= 3 then [G3_Plan Date]
when [CURRENT_GATE]= 4 then [G4_Plan Date]
when [CURRENT_GATE]= 5 then [G5_Plan Date]
when [CURRENT_GATE]= 6 then [G6_Plan Date]
End )
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Mencionas que "no fue posible", pero si hay un error, no indicas cuál es y, como puedes comprender, esta información es vital para poder entender cuál es el problema y probablemente sea el punto de partida para que un experto en tema pueda ayudarte a resolver la situación en que te encuentras. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderte. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Agrega el script de generación de la tabla